# Internal microphone doesn't work on an Acer Aspire 1410

Tags: 12.04, acer, microphone, aspire

Ubuntu 12.04 32bit
ACER Aspire 1410

The built in microphone will not pic up sound.
I have tried adjusting in pavucontrol, alsa mixer, and alsa-base.conf with various options:

options snd-hda-intel model= <-- "laptop" "acer" etc.

But...no luck!

The computer was previously running netbook remix. We were able to get the mic to work at that time by panning the audio to one channel as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue as follows:

1. Install GNOME Alsa Mixer from Ubuntu Software Center
2. Uncheck `inverted Internal Mic`.

Comment: I don't see this option!